# Подключение в проект библиотеки AppCompat без IDE

Tags: android

При попытке использовать стили вылетает такая ошибка:

> "No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'".

Работаю без IDE, собираю ant debug.

1. Копировал в libs библиотеки из support, 4, 7 и остальных версий.
2. Правил build.gradle
3. Пробовал собирать тестовые проекты.
4. Пробовал собирать чужие проекты с темами.
5. Гуглил. Гуглил. Гуглил.

Как это починить? Есть проект с темами который точно собирается? Если и он не соберется, какие варианты решения есть еще?

Comment: Если вы думаете, что IDE - это только подсветка кода , а без нее вы пишите более оптимальный код, то у меня для вас плохие новости. Лучшим решением вашей проблемы будет сделать над собой усилие, преодолеть лень и установить интегрированную среду разработки. В наше время разумнее Android Studio. Ох уж эти сишники, постоянно они ищут себе проблемы на ровном месте :)

Comment: Проект по умолчанию в Android Studio, как раз содержит то, что нужно

Comment: Как ни собирался Support7Demos, так и в студии не собирается.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Тема лежит во второй библиотеке.

Если вы используете этот способ, то собирайте через `gradle build`

Если `gradle` не установлен, то используйте вместо него `gradlew` - скрипт, лежащий в папке проекта

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не может быть в том, что вы прописываете зависимости в gradle.build, а пользуетесь ant-ом?

Answer (score -1):

[Вот из доков пример](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). Скажите какие плюсы в том что бы не использовать IDE?

Comment: Качал эти примеры. Не работают, хоть убейся. v4 и v13 работают,  но там не используются стили.   Мне было лень ставить эклипс. Минусы: нет подсветки кода. Плюсы: пишу более оптимальный код.

Comment: mikelsv, можете залить проект на гитхаб я попробую собрать.

Comment: @mikelsv оптимальный код ? с чего ты взял ? :)

Comment: @argamidon , автор под С\С++ разрабатывает , у них это "патология" . Дух программистов семидесятых - трудности ради трудностей :)

Comment: Задолбался, но поставил Android Studio, импортировал Support7Demos, собираю. Та же ошибка. Я вот это пытаюсь собрать https://github.com/omertex/AndroidNavigationDrawerTabs . Мне всего-то надо понять, как работают фрагменты и боковое меню. А я трачу кучу времени эту ерунду.